# QGIS not providing accurate grid lines on exported map

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grids-graticules

When I apply a grid to my map in the QGIS 'Layout Manager', the grid lines seem to begin from 0.00000 on the x/y axes, opposed to the accurate grid coords. As seen here in my exported map:

[image: map.jpg]

Here are my 'Map Grid Propeties' settings:

[image: map_grid_props]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `interval units` should be set to `map unit`, i.e. in degrees.

I **believe** the CRS is not used unless `map unit` is selected.

[image]

[image]